# Can't make greasemonkey click the Default View or Cinema View button

Tags: javascript, youtube, greasemonkey

I am new to javascript and I tried to write a piece of code that would click a button depending on the width of the browser. If the size of the window is over 50% of my monitor I want it to press the button for the default view and when it is under 50% I want it to press the button for cinema view.

I have tried changing the "window.onload" to "window.addEventListener("load", function()" and I even added a timeout just to make sure the elements were loaded. This is my current code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (window.innerWidth > window.screen.width / 2) {
            // select the element with the title "Default mode (t)"
            var defaultModeButton = document.querySelector('button[title="Default mode (t)"]');
            // click the element
            defaultModeButton.click();
        }else{
            // select the element with the title "Cinema mode (t)"
            var cinemaModeButton = document.querySelector('button[title="Cinema mode (t)"]');
            // click the element
            cinemaModeButton.click();
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

What am I missing? Can somebody help me out?

Comment: We need more info. What are the userscript headers? In which page is the script running?

Comment: Do you get any console errors? What happens if you put `console.log("01")` right before `setTimeout(...)`? What happens when you `console.log(...)` inside of your `if/else`? Have you tried using `setInterval(...)`, instead of `setTimeout(...)`, just to see if the buttons will ever be clicked? The buttons you're querying the DOM for - do they exist?